# Jenkins - What's changed between 2 builds?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, changelog, jelly

I have a Jenkins build pipeline with a manual task of deploy to QA environment.

When the project is invoked I want to be able to aggregate the change log from the current build to the last built that was deployed to the QA environemnt.

I see the way to do this through the change log. However there doesn't seem to be a easy way to get this information and then aggregate it.

Any ideas on how to achieve this aim?

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing but I was unable to find any Jenkins plugin functionality to achieve it.

I used the 'Execute Shell' build step and coded the required functionality in shell script.  We run Jenkins on Linux, if you are using Windows you can achieve the same this using the 'Execute Windows Batch command' build step

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of how to achieve this via shell?

Answer (score 0):

The [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) can do something like this. It allows to configure the emails that are sent by Jenkins in great detail, among them is scripting of the email-contents.

The provided sample at https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html-with-health-and-console.jelly shows how the change set can be iterated and listed in the resulting email notification:

```
<!-- CHANGE SET -->
<div class="content">
  <j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
  <j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
    <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
    <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/changes">
      <h1>Changes</h1>
    </a>
    <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet.logs}" varStatus="loop">
      <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
      <h2>${cs.msgAnnotated}</h2>
      <p>by <em>${cs.author}</em></p>
      <table>
        <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.affectedFiles}">
          <tr>
            <td width="10%">${spc}${p.editType.name}</td>
            <td>
              <tt>${p.path}</tt>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </j:forEach>
      </table>
    </j:forEach>
    <j:if test="${!hadChanges}">
      <p>No Changes</p>
    </j:if>
    <br />
  </j:if>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to only show the changes on the current build. I want the change set across multiple builds, aggregated together.